# Evaluating a syntax tree for arithmetic expressions

Tags: types, eval, sml, ml

Could you help me with next task:
I should have a function

```
fun eval (fn : (string * int) list -> expression -> int)
```

that gets a list of tuples (variable_name, value) and an expression. The function uses currying and returns the evaluated value of the expression. It should at least support operators `+, -, *, /, %` that represent addition, subtraction, multiplication, integer division and remainder

For next datatype:

```
datatype expression = Constant of int
                    | Variable of string
                    | Operator of string * expression
                    | Pair of expression list
                    | List of expression list
```

Any suggestion or explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Should `Pair of expression list` be `Pair of expression * expression`?. In any event, you could build up to it. A special case of an expression is one which involves at most 1 variable. Write a 1-variable `eval1` of type `int -> expression -> int` where any expression of the form `Variable _` evaluates to the int which is passed to `eval1`. Once you get `eval1` written, it should be straightforward (though not quite trivial) to modify it to get `eval`. Use pattern matching against the constructors of `expression` to define `eval1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a skeleton:

```
fun lookup var1 ((var2,value)::rest) = ...
  | lookup var1 [] = raise Fail ("Variable " ^ var1 ^ " not found")

fun eval vtable exp =
    case exp of
         Constant i => i
       | Variable v => lookup ...
       | Operator (oper, subexp) => evalOp vtable oper subexp
       | Pair _ => raise Fail "Pair at unexpected position in syntax tree!"
       | List _ => raise Fail "List at unexpected position in syntax tree!"

and evalOp vtable oper exp =
    let val operands =
            case exp of ... (* calling eval on sub-expressions allowed *) ...
    in case oper of
            "+" => ...add operands...
          | "-" => ...subtract operands...
          | ...
    end
```

Here are some thoughts:

- Problem-solving wise: Divide the problem into several sub-parts. For example, making a helper function that looks up a variable in vtable is a given. Handling operators in a separate helper function has less obvious benefits - mainly I'm just trying to avoid nesting *case-of*s for legibility. Because the datatype has too much flexibility (can express, what seems to me, nonsensical expressions), handling that flexibility in the right spots seems to warrant a division here, too.
- If a `Pair` is supposed to always contain two operands, you could write this part as `val (op1, op2) = case exp of ...`, but if they sometimes reduce to a list of values on which the operator must work with some assumption of associativity, perhaps simply `map eval sub_exps` where `sub_exps` is the evaluated list of expressions found within either `Pair` or `List`.
- As John says, the syntax tree you are given seems to reflect some undesired properties. For example, `Pair [Constant 1, Constant 2, Constant 3]` is a peculiar pair. What does `Operator ("-", Pair [Constant 1, Constant 2, Constant 3])` mean? And what about `Operator ("/", [])`? Why even have both `Pair` and `List` when they both take a list? When does `List` fit in? And why are pairs legal expressions? What integer value should they evaluate to?

  **Moral: Good data types only have meaningful values.**

  An alternative datatype that might do the trick:

  ```
  datatype expression = Constant of int
                      | Variable of string
                      | Operator of string * expression * expression
               (* or: | Operator of string * expression list *)
  ```

  This datatype is easier to evaluate, too, because there are fewer odd/wrong corner-cases to handle:

  ```
  fun getOp "+" = op +
    | getOp "-" = op -
    | getOp "*" = op *
    | getOp "/" = op div
    | getOp "%" = op mod
    | getOp oper = raise Fail ("Unsupported operator " ^ oper)

  fun eval vtable (Constant i) = i
    | eval vtable (Variable s) = lookup ...
    | eval vtable (Operator (oper, exp1, exp2)) =
        getOp oper (eval vtable exp1, eval vtable exp2)
  ```

  Unfortunately, your syntax tree requires a lot of probing for invalid values.
- If this is homework, remember to make the proper copyright attribution in your source code. ;-)

Comment: Datatype I put above, is the specific one I need to use for this task, so I cannot modify that, task is formulated like that.

Comment: @NSX23 If that is the case, then perhaps `eval` is supposed to be a partial function (in much the same way that `hd` is a partial function on lists). Perhaps the constructors `Pair` and `List` are not intended to be top-level expressions but are intended solely to play a role in `Operator`. There doesn't seem to be any non-arbitrary way to get a single value from a list of expressions. If you insist on giving those a value, returning the last value in the list seems idiomatic (expression lists in SML evaluate to the last expression, though in the absence of side effects it is pointless).